# C# implicit conversion and conversion from Object

Tags: c#, .net, implicit-conversion

There is a class:

```
public class Date
{
    private DateTime _dateTime;

    public Date(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime(Date d)
    {
        if (d == null)
            return default(DateTime);

        return d._dateTime;
    }

    public static implicit operator Date(DateTime dt)
    {
        return new Date(dt);
    }
}
```

So, this code works fine:

```
Date d = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt=new Date(DateTime.Now);
```

But this code doesn't work and throws InvalidCastException "Specified cast is not valid.":

```
Date d = DateTime.Now;
var obj = (Object)d;
DateTime dt = (DateTime)obj;
```

For me, this is expected behavior, but is there any hack to make this particular  code work?
(Without cast obj to Date)

Comment: Use `dynamic` (change obj as dynamic instead of object), or cast `obj` to `Date` are the only options I can think of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

User defined implicit/explicit conversion operators are an entirely compile time construct.  The compiler is going to say something alone the lines of, "Hey, this person is trying to stick a Foo somewhere that expects a Bar.  Is a Foo a Bar?  No, it's not.  Hmm...Oh, I see that Foo has defined an implicit conversion to Bar, I'll go stick in a call to that static conversion method, so that at runtime all of the types match up."

The runtime has no knowledge about implicit/explicit conversions.  By the time the program has finished being compiled, those are just regular static methods, like any other static method.  Since the compiler only sees conversions from `Date` to `object` and from `object` to `Date`, it never sees a place where it needs to add the implicit conversion calls.  By the time the runtime gets to it, it only sees that the `Date` isn't a `DateTime`.

Comment: Actually runtime knows more (exact obj and target type) then compiler. The real problem is that would incur virtual dispatch on every failed cast, interfere with static type system and doesn't align with other C family languages.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion operators are resolved based on static types (compile-time), since they are not `virtual`/`abstract`.

You can use `dynamic` (with all implications of using `dynamic`) to opt in to run-time reflection based look up.

```
Date d = DateTime.Now;
var obj = (Object)d;
DateTime dt = (DateTime)(dynamic)obj;
```